# Using standard CAST rather than CONVERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, standards

These work when retrieving the first of the month, 6 months ago:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = SYSDATETIME();

--1
SELECT CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@Now)-5,0),112));

--2
SELECT CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(CHAR(6),DATEADD(mm,-5,@Now),112) + '01');
```

How do I achieve the same result using the standard function `CAST` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could do it this way, but it doesn't use `cast()`:

```
select (year(DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@Now)-5, 0))*10000 +
        month(DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@Now)-5, 0))*100
        +1)
```

Comment: (`CONVERT` is really useful in this situation!)

Comment: interesting solution - thanks. Can't remember his exact reasoning but I was recently on a course run by Itzik B-G and he had a specific reason to not use `0` but to use `19000101` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(year(dateadd(month, -5,@now)) as char(4)) 
+ right(100 + month(dateadd(month, -5,@now)), 2) + '01'
```

Alternative:

```
select cast(year(a.n) as char(4)) + right(100 + month(a.n), 2) + '01'
from (select dateadd(m,-5,@now) n) a
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Madhivanan's answer here is how you can use CAST instead of CONVERT :)

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @now) - 5, 0) AS DATE), '-', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficient method would be

```
select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@now)-5,0)
```

Comment: .....but I'm trying to get the result into an INT that is a date formatted like YYYYMMDD ?

Comment: That's presentation issue. Why do you want to do it using CAST?

Comment: ...It's not a presentation issue - it's a different type. Reason is as mentioned in OP - I'd like to not use MS's transact-sql function `CONVERT` but use the standard-sql function `CAST`.